# Suggest adding Japanese monospace fonts to the CSS

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

I posted a table in an [answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/14960/revisions) and formatted it using full-width space 　. I deliberately avoided <kbd>TAB</kbd> because it produces inconsistent results in different  machines.

I expected all full-width characters would be twice as wide as half-width characters, and it looked good on my notebook. However, it seems that it does not display well in some browses who default font is not Chinese or Japanese.

I suggest we should add at least a Japanese font for the following CSS classes: `.textarea`, `.pre`, `code`.

---

Using FULL-WIDTH SPACE

```
1-9　　　　　10-90　　　100-900　　1000-9000　　10000
1　ひとつ　　とを　　　　もも　　　　ち　　　　　よろづ
2　ふたつ　　はたち　　　ふたほ　　　ふたち　　　ふたよろづ
3　みつ　　　みそぢ　　　みほ　　　　みち　　　　みよろづ
4　よつ　　　よそぢ　　　よほ　　　　よち　　　　よよろづ
5　いつつ　　いそぢ　　　いほ　　　　いち　　　　いよろづ
6　むつ　　　むそぢ　　　むほ　　　　むち　　　　むよろづ
7　ななつ　　ななそぢ　　ななほ　　　ななち　　　ななよろづ
8　やつ　　　やそぢ　　　やは　　　　やち　　　　やよろづ
9　ここのつ　ここのそぢ　ここのほ　　ここのち　　ここのよろづ
```

Using TAB

```
	1-9	10-90	100-900	1k-9000	10000
1	ひとつ	とを	もも	ち	よろづ
2	ふたつ	はたち	ふたほ	ふたち	ふたよろづ
3	みつ	みそぢ	みほ	みち	みよろづ
4	よつ	よそぢ	よほ	よち	よよろづ
5	いつつ	いそぢ	いほ	いち	いよろづ
6	むつ	むそぢ	むほ	むち	むよろづ
7	ななつ	ななそぢ	ななほ	ななち	ななよろづ
8	やつ	やそぢ	やは	やち	やよろづ
9	ここのつ	ここのそぢ	ここのほ	ここのち	ここのよろづ
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I posted about this previously: http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1023/preformatted-text-in-japanese-doesnt-line-up-properly

Comment: Sorry about the edit on your question.  I was trying out the solution someone suggested, but I guess it didn't work out.  You can revert the changes if you like, of course.  (It would be best if SE fixed the bug, I think.)