# Furigana engine update

Tags: discussion, status-completed, furigana

As a follow up to [Furigana engine: modified version with various bugfixes, added features](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1066/), I've tried to fix various issues which have cropped up, and posted the changes to https://gist.github.com/cyphr/6536814.

Changes are:

- Fixed `<strong>` and `<em>` tags with Furigana as at [Why doesn't furigana work in italicized or bolded text?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/532/why-doesnt-furigana-work-in-italicized-or-bolded-text)
- `pre` blocks and `code` tags with Japanese text in them now use a Japanese font to fix [Preformatted text in Japanese doesn't line up properly](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1023/preformatted-text-in-japanese-doesnt-line-up-properly) and [Suggest adding Japanese monospace fonts to the CSS](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1162/suggest-adding-japanese-monospace-fonts-to-the-css) (`pre`/`code` tags which don't contain Japanese text still display using the original non-Japanese monospaced fonts for increased readability of e.g. rōmaji linguistic explanations and English `pre` tables on Anime.SE etc).
- A fix for [Chrome Kanji renderings murdering my eyes: how to fix?](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1141/chrome-kanji-renderings-murdering-my-eyes-how-to-fix/) by explicitly making Japanese use Japanese fonts (in all browsers/OSes, not just Chrome) as well as working around [this Chrome OS issue](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=339317) by adding `xml:lang="ja"` on Japanese text.
- A workaround for [ruby getting squished on some mobile WebKit/Blink](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/511?m=17474056) browsers, like Chrome on Android by making ruby a px font size if the ruby base text isn't similar in size to the surrounding text.
- Made the browser title not have Furigana markup display for aesthetic reasons.
- A fix for a bug where certain paragraphs wouldn't display Furigana due to a regular expression issue (`regex.test('...')` being used instead of `'...'.match(regex)`).
- Implemented [Earthling's suggestions](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1245/796) so that お・ご honorifics work before Furigana, and `[漢字]​【かな】` syntax/fullwidth braces as at [Furigana in Japanese input mode using { }](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/789/furigana-in-japanese-input-mode-using) now work.

  I also added `漢字​{かな}` syntax to the "help" text on the right of https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/ask. It was decided a long time ago at [Deciding on an "officially recommended" format for furigana on JLU](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339/deciding-on-an-officially-recommended-format-for-furigana-on-jlu) that `漢字​【かな】` syntax was to be preferred (and I think it visually is more attractive), but it's harder to input `【】` characters than `{}｛｝` and many people don't know how to do it.
- `[[`...`]]` and `//`...`//` and `[/`...`/]` syntax in non-`<pre>`/`<code>` tags now display in a font that can display IPA as at [IPA and diacritic rendering](https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1287/ipa-and-diacritic-rendering).

The mobile site is theoretically supported as well, but I don't know whether this script can be added to it.

P.S. I'm not as active here as I once was, so if anyone wants to take over the development of this script feel free. Otherwise, I'll try to maintain/add features to it as the community here decides - please post any requests here in this thread, or as a separate meta post with a link to the post in the comments and I'll see what I can do :)

Comment: Yay!​​​​​​​​​​​

Answer (score 1):

This was a little weird:

[image]

But istrasci fixed it!

[image]

Here's the revision in question:

[image]

https://japanese.stackexchange.com/posts/18857/revisions

Comment: uh, yeah...I rolled out a fix (of sorts) for this issue to GitHub half an hour or so ago :) Basically "目覚め" with furigana "め・ざ・" containing character separators caused a `<rb>め</rb>` with a blank `<rt></rt>` to be created. I've made it so that blank or the same Furigana with character separation syntax outputs without Furigana, but you still have to have separators for each character separately as it is currently, e.g. "目覚める" can now be "め・ざ・め・る" or "め・ざ・・" but "め・ざ・める" won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it applies to everyone, but I have a problem with full-width and half-width tilde characters: I can produce three of them, two full-width and one half-width.

The full-width tilde renders differently, loosely depending on whether a Japanese or Latin character follows or precedes it or doesn't:

> Cf.「～で記入して」 and
>   「～で記入して」
>
> **Screenshot**
>
> [image: screenshot]

(same tilde in both cases)

It's a small thing, but I've tried to put in ～から～まで (same tilde!) and failed.

The issue already is present in the input text field.

Comment: This should mostly be fixed in the updated version, as Japanese fonts will be used for both fullwidth Latin and Japanese (img: http://postimg.org/image/hurzsioyx/). Previously, Japanese fonts weren't explicitly specified, and it used the OS/font rendering system to find a font to display glyphs that weren't found. I don't think there's much I can do about the input text field short of using a Japanese font, unfortunately like I said on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17882754#17882754) I think that could be worse than the disease.

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot?  On my system on both SeaMonkey and Chrome they render the same way.  But I think this could be related to [East Asian ambiguous characters](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr11/#Ambiguous).  Is `〜` considered to have ambiguous width in Unicode?

Comment: @snailboat Actually, the difference is more visible on my system, so I updated my post with my own screenshot.