# Is there a way to use the furigana and pitch accent engine for other websites?

Tags: discussion, furigana

I would like to include the code for the furigana this site uses into my website. Is it publicly available? How do I implement it? Thanks.

Comment: https://japanese.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1277/1628 please take a look here, whether you can find information about the license for the furigana engine, and if not maybe try to contact cypher via a comment.

Comment: I know but it seems to be designed to work for this site only, is there a way to transpose this to another site? TBH how do you get the pitch accent and furigana hover tap reveal? I am more interested in that